# Returning empty response using ES6 promise in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

how can I call a query using ES6 native promises in node.js. Below is the code.

```
let arr= [];
    conn.query('select * from table1', (err, b) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        console.log(b[i]["id"])
        let promiseGetData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            conn.query('select * from table2 where id = ?', [b[i]["id"]], (err, ce) => {
                if (err) {
                    const response = {
                        statusCode: 500,
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            message: err
                        }),
                    }
                    reject(response);
                } else {
                    if (ce.length != 0) {
                        resolve(ce);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        promiseGetData .then((data) => {
            b[i]['data'] = data;
            arr.push(b[i])
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
console.log(b)
    })
```

I see an empty response when i do console.log(b). I dont know if I have used a promise in correct way, I think for first query I should execute in the promise as well. Any help is very  much appreciated

Comment: Have you considered the case where ce.length == 0 and there isn't an error?

Comment: @GrantPark yes I have checked that there is no error, actually I have placed the console.log before a second query and i can see a log but not the query data afterwards, but still I will double check that again with case ce.length == 0

Comment: In that case, also place a console.log in your second query and see if that runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got empty response from console.log(b) because the promise from querying database aren't finished. You have to wait all of them to finish before you can get the full result.

Sample:

```
let arr = [];
conn.query('select * from table1', (err, b) => {

  var promiseArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        let promiseGetData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            conn.query('select * from table2 where id = ?', [b[i]["id"]], (err, ce) => {
                if (err) {
                    const response = {
                        statusCode: 500,
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            message: err
                        }),
                    }
                    reject(response);
                } else {
                    if (ce.length != 0) {
                        resolve(ce);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

            promiseArr.push(promiseGetData);
    }

    Promise.all(promiseArr).then((resultArr) => {
        //resultArr is all the resolved value returned from the promise in promiseArr
        for (let i = 0; i < resultArr.length; i++) {
            b[i]['data'] = resultArr[i];
            arr.push(b[i]);
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log(arr);
    }).catch((err) => {
        //if any promise throw/reject with error, it will go here directly
            console.log(err);
    });
})
```

Edit:
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I have one question should the 1st query be in promise too?

Comment: yes, you should. It's a good practice to either use promise or callback for the whole application but not both in favor of better code management and readability. Actually the sample code from @drinchev is very clean and helpful. Check it if you can understand it.

Comment: @iKoala Thanks I will check it

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping an async callback-based function into a promise is called `Promisifying`.

You can of course use a library for that, but basically what it does is :

```
const queryAsPromise = function( ...args ) {
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
       try { 
           conn.query(...args, function( error, result ) {
               if ( error ) { 
                   reject( error );
               } else {
                   resolve( result );
               }
           } ); 
       } catch( error ) {
           reject( error );
       }
    } )
} );
```

By doing this one time you will keep your code DRY and you can always use that promise for making queries now :

```
queryAsPromise('select * from table1')
     .then( result => {
          return Promise.all(
              result.map( b => {
                 return queryAsPromise('select * from table2 where id = ?', b["id"])
                             .then( data => b["data"] = data )
              } )
          )
     )
     .catch( err => res.send(500) )
     .then( console.log )
```

Comment: you forgot to handle the params passing to the query in the example :)

Comment: Ahh, Good catch! :D